# warning as Control reaches at the end of a non-void function when implementing binary search

Tags: c++, binary-search

This is my implementation of binary search. Though the get the answer correctly, when I compile the code I get a warning stating "Control reaches at the end of a non-void function". Why am I getting this error? How to correct it?
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary1(int myarray[7], int target) 
{
    int low=1, high=sizeof(myarray);
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
        if(myarray[mid]==target)
            return mid;
        else if(myarray[mid]<target)
            low=mid+1;
        else
            high=mid-1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[7] ={3,7,12,44,53,76,98};
    int value = binary1(a,53);
    cout<<value<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't know for certain that `low <= high`, so it's possible that your `while` loop may terminate (consider the case where the element you are searching for is not found). In that case, you would get to the end of the `binary1` function without a `return` statement. This is invalid because your function returns `int`.

Comment: How can I overcome this now?

Comment: Return something at the end of the function after the close of the `while` loop. In your case, maybe -1 would be a good value to indicate "item not found".

Answer (score 1):

If the function is passed a value which is not present in your container it will reach the end of function. Going into the depths of function calling and how value is returned (for starters check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)) is beyond the scope of this question,but we can say that the behavior is implementation dependent. 
When I call your function with these parameters ({3,7,12,44,53,76,98},1) your code returns 0 on ideone.

You should return a value in case the value is not found which is impossible to get when an element is actually present in the container. -1 should do.

I would have written the function like this:

```
int binary1(int myarray[7], int target) 
{
    int low=1, high=sizeof(myarray);
    int idx = -1;
    while(low<=high)
    {
        int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
        if(myarray[mid]==target){
            idx = mid;
            break;  // answer already found.
          }
        else if(myarray[mid]<target)
            low=mid+1;
        else
            high=mid-1;
    }
  return idx;
}
```